# menupopup event listener not get called?

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces

I'm using ice:menuPopup to create menus on tree nodes. In jspx page I've something like this

```
<ice:tree id="tree" value="#{tree.model}" var="item" imageDir="./xmlhttp/css/xp
                                                                         /css-images/">  
      <ice:treeNode>  
           <f:facet name="icon">  
                 <ice:panelGroup style="display: inline">  
                         <h:graphicImage value="#{item.userObject.icon}"/>  
                 </ice:panelGroup>  
           </f:facet>  
           <f:facet name="content">  
                 <ice:panelGroup style="display: inline" menuPopup="menuPopupEffects">  
                       <ice:commandLink actionListener="#{tree.Url}" value="#
                                                              {item.userObject.text}"/>   
                 </ice:panelGroup>  
           </f:facet>  
                 <ice:menuPopup id="menuPopupEffects">  
                       <ice:menuItem value="Open" actionListener="#{tree.NodeValue}">  
                              <f:param name="effectType" value="Open"/>  
                      </ice:menuItem>
                      <ice:menuItem value="Close">  
                              <f:param name="effectType" value="Close"/>  
                      </ice:menuItem>  
                      <ice:menuItem value="Send">  
                              <f:param name="effectType" value="Send"/>  
                      </ice:menuItem>  
                 </ice:menuPopup>  
</ice:treeNode>
```

The problem is that the actionListener="#{tree.NodeValue}" never gets called. Can any one tell me Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move ice:menuPopup..../ice:menuPopup that block up, insert that block into the line just below:

```
ice:commandLink actionListener="#{tree.Url}" value="#
                     {item.userObject.text}"
```

Thus they in the same panelGroup. It works for me this way, but I am still use icefaces 1.8.